Method of Characteristics for this PDE and what's the problem with its domain?
$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}y -\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}x=1$ with $u(x,0)=0$ and $x\geq0$
By using the method of characteristics, I get $u=t$ and $x^2+y^2=x_0^2$.
The answer is $u=-\arctan(y/x)$. But I don't understand how to get that.
Also, there is apparently a problem with the domain.
It's said that the characteristic curves move in circles around the origin and that the value of $u$ must rise by $2\pi$ with the completion of each circle in the counter-clockwise direction. But this is impossible with the answer $u=-\arctan(y/x)$ apparently.
Could someone explain this intuition?

I suspect there is typo in the PDE. Shouldn't it be $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}y -\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}x=1?$

@Gonçalo I think the form I have changed it to is correct. With $u(x,y)$ given you get $\partial_x u(x,y)=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$, $\partial_yu(x,y)=\frac{-x}{x^2+y^2}$

@K.defaoite, with $u=-\arctan(y/x)$ one has $\partial_xu=+\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$.

@Gonçalo Sorry, you were right. Thanks for clearing that up. I have fixed the typo.

@Gonçalo Thanks for the correction. My mistake.
